# SAML generate metadata from entityId

Tags: web-services, web-applications, saml

I am trying to generate SAML metadata for Service provider,I have created simple servlet and trying to generate metadata in a methoad doGet()

this is the code I have tried below

```html
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpRetryException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


import org.opensaml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.EntityDescriptor;
import org.opensaml.xml.XMLObjectBuilderFactory;


public class MetadataProviderServlet extends HttpServlet{
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
  PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  writer.println("Hello world");
  
  String entityId = "www.sampleEntityId.com";
  
  XMLObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory = Configuration.getBuilderFactory();
   
  EntityDescriptor descriptor = (EntityDescriptor)(builderFactory.getBuilder(EntityDescriptor.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(EntityDescriptor.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME));
  descriptor.setEntityID(entityId);

  
  
  
 }
 
 

}
```

But when I run the web application using one application server I got the NUllpointer Exception in particularly creation the object Entity Descriptor.Can Anyone please figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the OpenSAML library first. OpenSAML is initialised using the bootstrap method.

```
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
```

I write about this on my blog [here](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2014/05/nullpointer-exception-in-opensaml.html)